# Getting punctuation from the end of a string only

Tags: c#

I'm looking for a C# snippet to remove and store any punctuation from the **end of a string only**.

Example:

- Test! would return !
- Test;; would return ;;
- Test?:? would return ?:?
- !!Test!?! would return !?!

I have a rather clunky solution at the moment but wondered if anybody could suggest a more succinct way to do this.

My puncutation list is

```
new char[] { '.', ':', '-', '!', '?', ',', ';' })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Linq:

```
var punctuationMap = new HashSet<char>(new char[] { '.', ':', '-', '!', '?', ',', ';' });
var endPunctuationChars = aString.Reverse().
                                  TakeWhile(ch => punctuationMap.Contains(ch));
var result = new string(endPunctuationChars.Reverse().ToArray());
```

The HashSet is not mandatory, you can use Linq's Contains on the array directly.

Comment: @Nick, from there you can do: string restOfTheWord = aString.SubString(0, aString.Length - result.Length);

Answer (score 7):

You could use the following regular expression:

```
\p{P}*$
```

This breaks down to:

```
\p{P}    - Unicode punctuation
*        - Any number of times
$        - End of line anchor
```

If you *know* that there will always be some punctuation at the end of the string, use `+` for efficiency.

And use it like this in order to get the punctuation:

```
string punctuation = Regex.Match(myString, @"\p{P}*$").Value;
```

To actually remove it:

```
string noPunctuation = Regex.Replace(myString, @"\p{P}*$", string.Empty);
```

Comment: +1 for Unicode. But better use `+` or a lot of unnecessary "replace nothing with nothing" operations will be carried out on strings that don't end in punctuation.

Comment: This would actually *match* the last punctuations, but not *remove* them.

Comment: @Tigran - True. I was working from his examples (where he wants the punctuation to be _returned_).

Comment: @TimPietzcker - Was considering that, but wrote it for the cases where the string didn't end with punctuation.

Answer (score 5):

Use a regex:

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"[.:!?,;-]+$", "");
```

**Explanation:**

```
[.:!?,;-]  # Match a character that's one of the enclosed characters
+          # Do this once or more (as many times as possible)
$          # Assert position at the end of the string
```

As Oded suggested, use `\p{P}` instead of `[.:!?,;-]` if you want to remove all punctuation characters, not just the ones from your list.

To also "store" the punctuation, you could split the string:

```
splitArray = Regex.Split(subjectString, @"(?=\p{P}+$)");
```

Then `splitArray[0]` contains the part before the punctuation, and `splitArray[1]` the punctuation characters. If there are any.

Comment: Will this only apply to the end of the alphanumeric string, not special characters before or in it.

Comment: @Nick: Yes. I hope the explanation I just added makes that clear.

Comment: It did - thanks for the explanation. How could I obtain the rest of the word easily?